# Haproxy backend stays down and is never brought up again

Tags: haproxy

It works fine up until the moment the remote server becomes unavailable for some time. In which case the server goes down in the logs and is never brought up again. Config is quite simple:

```
defaults
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 3600000
    timeout server 3600000
    log global
    option log-health-checks

listen amazon_ses
    bind 127.0.0.2:1234
    mode tcp
    no option http-server-close
    default_backend bk_amazon_ses

backend bk_amazon_ses
    mode tcp
    no option http-server-close
    server amazon email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:587 check inter 30s fall 120 rise 1
```

Here are the logs when the problem occurs:

```
Jul  3 06:45:35 jupiter haproxy[40331]: Health check for server bk_amazon_ses/amazon failed, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 30004ms, status: 119/120 UP. 
Jul  3 06:46:35 jupiter haproxy[40331]: Health check for server bk_amazon_ses/amazon failed, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 30003ms, status: 118/120 UP. 
Jul  3 06:47:35 jupiter haproxy[40331]: Health check for server bk_amazon_ses/amazon failed, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 30002ms, status: 117/120 UP.
...
Jul  3 08:44:36 jupiter haproxy[40331]: Health check for server bk_amazon_ses/amazon failed, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 30000ms, st
atus: 0/1 DOWN. 
Jul  3 08:44:36 jupiter haproxy[40331]: Server bk_amazon_ses/amazon is DOWN. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 
0 remaining in queue. 
Jul  3 08:44:36 jupiter haproxy[40331]: backend bk_amazon_ses has no server available!
```

And that's it. Nothing but operator intervention brings the server back to life. I also tried removing the check part and what follows it - still the same thing happens. Can't haproxy be configured to try indefinitely and not mark a server DOWN? Thanks.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks! https://serverfault.com/questions/919281/haproxy-backend-stays-down-and-is-never-brought-up-again